# android notification firebase

Tags: php, android, firebase, android-notifications

I send a notification to android through PHP, and it gets normal on android.

But when I send more than one, it only shows the last one, and I wanted it to show all of them.

is it possible?

How can i do this?

PHP

```
$msg = array
          (
        'nome'  => $comando,
          );
    $fields = array
            (
                'to'    => $token,
                'data'  => $msg
            );


    $headers = array
            (   
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: key= KEY'               
            );

#Send Reponse To FireBase Server    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

#Echo Result Of FireBase Server
echo $result;
```

android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1410,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
                        NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setSound(alert)
                        .setContentTitle("teste")
                        .setContentText("teste "+msg+"!")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                        .setPriority(2)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager)
                                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy:

```
notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
```

you have written **'1410'**, Instead of that assign **Unique_Integer_number every time.**

> To get unique no everytime:

```
Random random = new Random();
int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `1410` from this line and change PendingIntent line also.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1410,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Add this line for generate unique id and use it to notify .

```
int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Cancel all the notifications before notifying the new one..

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();

notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
 notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
```

the first parameter id should be different for each notification . Otherwise it will override the previous one .

A simple way around is to Use SharedPreference to get and store the Id . And each time use a incremented one. See the example below.

```
 private int getNotificationId(){
    SharedPreferences  sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int lastId=sp.getInt("notify_id",0);
    sp.edit().putInt("notify_id",lastId+1).commit();
    return lastId;
}

 notificationManager.notify(getNotificationId(), notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

In android code you are using only one notification id, change it to dynamic and you will see all notifications.

change following line:

```
notificationManager.notify(getUniqueId(), notificationBuilder.build());

...
private int getUniqueId() {
    return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and no unique id for each `Notification`. Use this for showing `Notification` -

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        int uniqueNotificationId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class); // Where you will go after clicking on notification 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueNotificationId /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

       //PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueNotificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(uniqueNotificationId  /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```